# How to set python variables to true or false?

Tags: python-2.7, boolean, constants

I want to set a variable in Python to true or false.  But the words `true` and `false` are interpreted as undefined variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = true; 
b = true;
if a == b:          
  print("same");
```

The error I get:

```
a = true
NameError: global name 'true' is not defined
```

What is the python syntax to set a variable true or false?

Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 75, accepted):

First to answer your question, you set a variable to true or false by assigning [`True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#True) or [`False`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#False) to it:

```
myFirstVar = True
myOtherVar = False
```

If you have a condition that is basically like this though:

```
if <condition>:
    var = True
else:
    var = False
```

then it is much easier to simply assign the result of the condition directly:

```
var = <condition>
```

In your case:

```
match_var = a == b
```

Comment: **capital F** is what I needed to see :-) thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
match_var = a==b
```

that should more than suffice

you cant use a - in a variable name as it thinks that is `match` (minus) `var`

```
match=1
var=2

print match-var  #prints -1
```

Answer (score 6):

Python boolean keywords are `True` and `False`, notice the capital letters.  So like this:

```
a = True;
b = True;
match_var = True if a == b else False
print match_var;
```

When compiled and run, this prints:

```
True
```

Comment: yes that would work too (so would just changing the variable name and using = instead of set/to ... in addition I can think of no cases where you would want to do this when you are setting the value to a boolean ...

Answer (score 3):

you have to use capital True and False not true and false

Answer (score 0):

as Poke said:

> If you have a condition that is basically like this though:
>
> ```
> if <condition>:
>     var = True
> else:
>     var = False
> ```
>
> then it is much easier to simply assign the result of the condition
> directly:
>
> ```
> var = <condition>
> ```

but if you want to reverse it you can use:

```
var = <condition> is False
```